# Using to_sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie...

I know how to use "to_sentence" when I have something like:

```
<%= @blah.collect {|b| b.name}.to_sentence %>
```

but what if I have a more complex block like:

```
<% skill.position.each do |position| %>              
  <a href="<%= position.company.url %>"><%= position.company.name %></a>
  <% if position.salary? %>
    <span><%= position.salary %></span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The desired output is:

```
Microsoft, Google 2000, and Yahoo.
```

Comment: It's not very clear what kind of output you need for that `each`. Please give an example of the input and output desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just collect it without .each?

```
<%= skill.positions.collect{ |p| "<a href=\"#{p.company.url}\">#{p.company.name}</a>#{position.salary? ? '<span>#{position.salary}</span>' : nil}" }.to_sentence %>
```

That should work for you...

You could also do this:

```
<%= skill.position.each do |position| %>              
  <a href="<% position.company.url %>"><% position.company.name %></a>
  <% if position.salary? %>
    <span><% position.salary %></span>
  <% end %>
<% end.to_sentence %>
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that @dontangg's method is just as functional and allows you to keep the same code. However, collect is more efficient that each because each will try and render which is an expensive operation

Answer (score 1):

The to_sentence methods works on Arrays. The reason that it works on your first example...

```
<%= @blah.collect {|b| b.name}.to_sentence %>
```

... is because the `collect` method returns an `Array`. The each method in your second example will also work because `each` also returns an `Array`. So, this will work:

```
<% blah.each do |b| %>
  ...
<% end.to_sentence %>
```

Comment: <% end.to_sentence %> looks sexy and it almost worked, however I don't know why, but it produced a lot of these <Position:0x25f8b18>..

Comment: you need to remove the = from your <%= and add it to the beginning. I've appended my answer to include this solution (in 30 seconds)